# Cannot use WSL anymore

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I cannot use WSL(*Ubuntu on Windows*). When I run `bash` in CMD, I will get an error

> Error:0x8007001f

But I can use it normally before some days, I don't know which my operation result in this problem. Please help me out.

Comment: `0x8007001f` appears to be an update error of some description. If you have the Fall Creators Update have you installed Ubuntu from the Windows Store? https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6

Comment: @Mokubai Thanks for save me. You solution is work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0x8007001f` appears to be an update error of some description.

If you have the Fall Creators Update have you may need to install Ubuntu from the Windows Store.

[Microsoft Store: Ubuntu](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6)

---

If you are missing the bash.exe command then apparently you need to [set up the default distribution](https://github.com/zeit/hyper/issues/2385#issuecomment-350677580) (as mentioned by nightwolfz in that thread):

> You can solve it by checking which distro's are installed with:
>
> ```
> wslconfig.exe /l
> ```
>
> and then setting default distro with:
>
> ```
> wslconfig.exe /s Ubuntu
> ```
>
> Enjoy fixed bash.exe !

This is necessary as you can now have [multiple different distributions installed](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/10/11/whats-new-in-wsl-in-windows-10-fall-creators-update/).

Comment: I realise the problem is still, I mean, I can run WSL [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqoig.png) now. But I [cannot startup WSL by run `bash` in `CMD`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCZms.png)

Comment: @yode added to my answer

Comment: Thanks anyway, it seem my old Ubuntu is broken. I enven cannot use `LxRun.exe /uninstall` to uninstall it..But I can normally use the new one now